# How to add text using append in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, passwords, generator

So I created python password generator. I want the password created to add itself to a txt file but I cant find a way. Heres the code:

```
  import random
passlen = int(input("enter the length of password "))
s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()?"
p = "".join(random.sample(s,passlen ))
file = open("pass.txt", "a")
file.write("Password: ")
file.close()
print(p)
file = open("pass.txt", "r")
print("Output of Readlines after appending")
print(file.read())
print()
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing `p` into `file`. Try:

```py
import random

passlen = 10
s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()?"

p = ''.join(random.sample(s, passlen))

with open('pass.txt', 'a') as f:
    print(f"password: {p}", file=f)

with open('pass.txt', 'r') as f:
    print("Now the contents of pass.txt:")
    print(f.read())
```

Note that `with open` is preferred (to `open ... close`) in general.

Comment: Thank you alot!!! I forgot to mention that I wanted each time the password is created, it saves to the document as password1, password2, etc. (Sorry for bothering, Im a beginner trying to learn python)